# NodeJS Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46

Tags: node.js, hexo

After I upgraded NodeJS and NPM to 6.2.0 and 3.9.3, when I run `hexo d -g` command to update my blog, I get the following error:

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bunyan/lib/bunyan.js:79:18)
{ Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bunyan/lib/bunyan.js:79:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
{ Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/dtrace-provider/dtrace-provider.js:17:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/node_modules/bunyan/lib/bunyan.js:79:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
(node) v8::ObjectTemplate::Set() with non-primitive values is deprecated
(node) and will stop working in the next major release.
```

I thought maybe Node.js is upgraded and `node_modules` should be reinstalled.

I tried `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`, but it doesn't work.  I also tried `sudo npm i -g npm` then `npm install hexo --no-optional --save`, which doesn't work neither.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: I prefer `mv node_modules old_node_modules` first, then `npm install`, then `rm -rf old_node_modules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexo doesn't seem to work with lastest version of node which is 6.2.0. You should use node-v4.4.5 (LTS) for a while, which is recommended version for most users.

Comment: Thanks bro, that really helps!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, after upgrading node, your installed packages kept compiled against the older version, and they need to be rebuilt. No need to delete node_modules, or running npm update.

Just run:

```
npm rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `hexo` is a globally installed package, but you only reinstalled it locally. Try to reinstall it globally:

```
npm install hexo -g
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Global installation files has not been update, please try to update your hexo-cli with command below:

`sudo npm install -g hexo-cli`

which solved my problem.